# Error with appcenter likely connected with python

Tags: appcenter, apt

I got this code when I open the appcenter. I recently dabbled in installing python stuff so might be connected to it. Also, when I ran sudo apt-update, this came out : [Error Message](https://pastebin.com/nVGmnK29)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and for me reinstalling apt_pkg work it, try:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-apt
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The error still happens.